# Class variable garbage collection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Was planning on using factory method to get singleton instance of a ruby class, but I'm not sure if its going to work with Ruby garbage collection.

EG if I have something like:

```
class Foo
def self.getInstance
  @@instance = Foo.new if @instance.nil?
  return @@instance
end

def counter
   @counter
end

 def increment
   @counter++
end

 private

 def initialize
     @counter = 0
 end
end
```

So the way this works in other languages I'm familiar with that the @instance survives garbage collection indefinitely, so that you Foo.getInstance.increment could be relied to have a continuiously ascending counter for the lifetime of the program.

However, I'm not sure what might be holding on to a reference to the the class's instance variable @@instance so will it get garbage collected?

Answer (score 2):

`@@instance` is a class var, not an instance var.  The class holds a references to its class vars which prevents their garbage collection until the class itself is undefined.

Please don't roll your own singleton pattern.  The stdlib has a module [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) which you can mixin to your class to make it a singleton.  The stdlib mixin looks after details you've forgotten, such as the thread safety of initialization and undefining `new`.

Comment: since you defined class Foo, by definition it cannot be Singleton; conversely, Singleton is the default when the class is undefined. Your class and instance variables are defined within class Foo, and self will hold the value of those (class for class variable, and object for instance variable)

Comment: @aug2uag You seem quite confused.  The OP is asking about a singleton instance, which implies a classic singleton pattern implementation. Perhaps you should look at the difinition of the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and Ruby's [Singleton Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html).  The OP is not asking about ruby "singleton" (aka eigen- or meta-) classes.

Comment: um, "In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object."

that's from the link you provided, and exactly what i addressed. Funny that i've started programming last year... looks to me you're the confused one son

Comment: @aug2uag if you're not confused, then why is your answer revolving around `class<<self;self;end`?

Comment: Sorry, I understand that @@instance is a class variable, that's the whole point.  Perhaps the proper way to phrase this is as a factory method which always returns the same single instance, rather than a singleton (new won't work because it is declared private).  .<br> My question actually is, what object is holding on to the Class object itself that prevents garbage collection of class variables like @@instance? Is it referenced and retained by some application object at the top of the hierarchy once a class method is called?

Comment: @user1023110 you have defined a class and assigned a reference to the class to the global constant `Foo`. The class referenced by `Foo` holds a live reference to the class var `@@instance`. As long as `Foo` is defined, there is a live reference to `@@instance` which will prevent it being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Make an instance method 'foo' and an instance variable with the same name as the method '@foo' use the singleton operator `||=` to assign or fetch an instance of `Foo`, If you do this from a class method you have produced a memory leak

```
def foo
  @foo ||= Foo.new
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The Singleton class is where object methods go when they're specific to that object, and each object may hold or holds such a class.

```
1.9.3p374 :315 > Jd = class<<self;self;end
 => #<Class:#<Object:0x007ff304078d08>> 
1.9.3p374 :316 > jd = Jd.new
TypeError: can't create instance of singleton class
    from (irb):316:in `new'
    from (irb):316
    from /Users/rfatahi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p374 :317 > Jd.class
 => Class
```

Adding method to Singleton class:

```
1.9.3p374 :318 > class MyClass
1.9.3p374 :319?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p374 :320 > a = MyClass.new
 => #<MyClass:0x007ff30605b530> 
1.9.3p374 :321 > def a.method1
1.9.3p374 :322?>   end
 => nil
```